# Fade div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a div that contains an image, when you hover over it another div appears containing text. Is there a way (using jquery or CSS) to add a fade effect?

Heres the code im using...

```
.work_box1, .work_box2, .work_box3 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 324px;
    width: 324px;
}
.work_title {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.work_box1:hover > .work_title, .work_box2:hover > .work_title, .work_box3:hover > .work_title {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Yes there is. Look at CSS3 transitions.

Comment: use css3 unless you have IE8 or lower in scope

Comment: For a jQuery solution if you go that route, look at jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) for how to do it with jquery. This could have been [googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+fadein+on+hover&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS492US492&oq=jquery+fadein+on+hover&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.5152j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) easy enough.

Comment: For CSS transitions, this is a good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 2):

here's my go at it: http://jsfiddle.net/5c324/1/

```
$("#myBox").mouseenter(function() {
     $( "#myBox" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.5, function() {});
});

$("#myBox").mouseout(function() {
     $( "#myBox" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 1.0, function() {});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) can do that. But for older browsers that can't do it without JS here's a jQuery solution:

```
$(".work_title").parent().hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".work_title").fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".work_title").fadeOut();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bddde/

Comment: p.s. that kitten is not cute, it's ugly ;)

Comment: @Accelerator - That's just because of the OP's existing styles. It happens even with the non-animated version done just with the OP's CSS, so fixing it is outside the scope of my answer. But still, here's a version that doesn't jump: http://jsfiddle.net/bddde/1/

Comment: The fiddle I added in my last comment doesn't jump at all for me (tested only in Chrome).

Comment: I'm using Chrome and your new link still jumps around on hover.

Comment: @Accelerator - Weird. The [fiddle from my last comment](http://jsfiddle.net/bddde/1/) definitely doesn't jump for me in Chrome or FF or IE. Anyway, as I said earlier, that jumping from the first version where I didn't change the OP's styles happens even with the OP's original CSS-only non-fade styles, so I'm not really interested in spending a lot of time trying to fix it when the question was just about adding a fade effect.

Comment: That fiddle that you say doesn't jump, well it jumps all over the place, and I am also using Chrome.

Comment: @Accelerator - Well I can't explain that. Doesn't jump at all for me, tested in three different browsers. Only the original version jumps (I didn't update the link in my question though, I just added a new one in the comments.)

Comment: Jumps for me. I even tried multiple browser widths still jumps every time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the `work_title` class is applied to the text annotations that overlay your images. In that case, you can use CSS3 transitions to fade them in and out when the mouse moves over them.

```
.work_title {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.work_title:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
```

If you want to support IE8, you'll have to include rules for `filter` as well as `opacity` -- I'll leave you to figure out how to do this :-)